# Create another txt file on the sd card if there is already an existing file using FATFS

Tags: c, stm32, sd-card, fatfs

I want to store some data to sd card using FATFS (STM32 micro-controller), but i have a problem i want to create a new file every time if there is already a file (from older experiments). So can someone give an example how to do that? For example if there is already an existing file called TEST1.TXT on the sd card, the program should create TEST2.TXT, if TEST2.TXT exist then TEST3.TXT and so on...

```
    FATFS myFATAFS;
FIL myFILE;

unsigned int testByte;

    if(f_mount(&myFATAFS,SD_Path, 1)== FR_OK){


    char myPath[] = "TEST1.TXT\n";
    f_open(&myFILE, myPath, FA_WRITE | FA_CREATE_NEW);

        //do something  

    f_close(&myFILE);
     HAL_GPIO_TogglePin(LED2_GPIO_type, LED2_GPIO_pin);
}
```

Comment: read the directory, then find the last file number, create a new one with the new number. BTW show us your effort.  FATFS documentation shows how to read the directory.

Comment: especially `Directory Access

    f_opendir - Open a directory
    f_closedir - Close an open directory
    f_readdir - Read a directory item
    f_findfirst - Open a directory and read the first item matched
    f_findnext - Read a next item matched`